# Scale Factor on Error

Tags: measurements, statistics, error-analysis

I was gathering some data from the particle data group website and for many results it gives a value, an uncertainty and then a scale factor for the uncertainty. For instance, at [here](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/DataBlock.action?node=M026M), where it gives the mass for the singlet ground state of charmonium, it says the error contains a scale factor of 1.3. Could anyone help me understand what is meant by this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in [this paper](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-rpp-intro.pdf). Quoting from it (page 10):

[image]

> Our reasoning is as follows. The large value of the χ2 is likely to be due to
> underestimation of errors in at least one of the experiments. Not knowing which of the
> errors are underestimated, we assume they are all underestimated by the same factor S.
> If we scale up all the input errors by this factor, the χ2 becomes N − 1, and of course the
> output error δx scales up by the same factor.